# How can i display for each loop to textbox in c#?

Tags: c#, rsa

I have a problem to display fo result of my looping code, this is my code

```
    private int n = 689;
    private int e = 41;
    private int d = 137;

    public void enkrip()
    {
        string text = "indra";

        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            int vout = Convert.ToInt32(asciiBytes[i]);
            int c = (int)BigInteger.ModPow(vout, e, n);
            char cipher = Convert.ToChar(c);
            textBox2.Text = char.ToString(cipher);
        }
    }
```

but it not appear in textbox, any help?

Comment: In addition to the already given answer, you can use `cipher.ToString();` instead of calling that method directly from the `char` class

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the text in your box with each loop.

If you want the final string in your text box, your loop should build a string, and then once the loop is done, put the final string into your text box.

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of the loop you're setting the `Text` to a single character. Build the string up, and assign it to the `text` outside the loop

```
string text = "indra";

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
char[] result = new char[text.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    int vout = Convert.ToInt32(asciiBytes[i]);
    int c = (int)BigInteger.ModPow(vout, e, n);
    char cipher = Convert.ToChar(c);
    result[i] = cipher;
}
textBox2.Text = new string(result);
```

Comment: Im afraid I cant help diagnose that unless you tell me what the error is!

Comment: sorry, that my mistake, your code work properly,
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever going to see the *last* value in the text box, since you over-write the text box's `.Text` property in every iteration of the loop.  Even if the UI does update between loop iterations, it would be too fast to perceive.

You could *append* to the text box in each iteration:

```
textBox2.Text += char.ToString(cipher);
```

Or perhaps build a string in the loop and then set the text box afterward (generally the preferred solution):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    //...
    sb.Append(char.ToString(cipher));
}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but still i confuse, why the last character is missing.

Comment: @Indra776: I'm not really sure.  But stepping through in a debugger should help you identify that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want a *combine* all the results into a *single* `string`:

```
  public void enkrip() {
     string text = "indra";

     byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

     // "iùŢĕ" 
     textBox2.Text = String.Concat(asciiBytes   
       .Select(b => (char)BigInteger.ModPow(b, e, n)));
  }
```

please note, that `asciiBytes.Length` and `text.Length` are different values (in general case). To represent encrypted text as hex codes:

```
  public void enkrip() {
     string text = "indra";

     byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

     // 0069, 00f9, 0162, 0115, 001c
     textBox2.Text = String.Join(", ", asciiBytes   
       .Select(b => BigInteger.ModPow(b, e, n).ToString("x4")));
  }
```

My final suggestion is to *extract a method*:

```
  public static String Encrypt(String text) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
      return text;

    int n = 689;
    int e = 41;

    return String.Concat(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
      .Select(b => (char)BigInteger.ModPow(b, e, n)));
  }

  ...

  // and so you can encrypt as easy as
  textBox2.Text = Encrypt("indra");
```

Comment: okay, thanks,
but why the length of the result not same with text?
can you explain it?

Comment: @Indra776: the last character has a code `1c` (or `28`) so it's command character `FS` (File Separator) and thus has not been displayed. In my edit, I've shown you characters' codes as well. If you want not to have command characters add 32 when encrypting (and subtract 32 when decrypting)

Comment: i understand now, that make me confuse why the last character was gone,
thanks for your help